# Question about Infinite Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Problem: The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverge and positive. What can be said on the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+n^{2}a_n}$ ?

Approach:

1. First, I tried separating it into two cases: $a_n \to \infty$, $a_n \to A$ (where $A$ is some const value).
2. Tried the ratio test and got nowhere with that.

I think that the right approach is to check each case separately, but my hunch tells me that there is a workaround.

Comment: Those are not the only cases.  a_n can oscillate or even tend to zero slowly.  (Casework is the way to go, though.)

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Rewrite as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_n} + n^2}.$$

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I was not sure I can divide it by $a_n$. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Ma. H: Maybe I misunderstood.  I read your first sentence as implying that all the terms in the series are positive and that the series diverges.  Is that not correct?  If $a_n >0$ for all $n$ then you can divide by $a_n$.

Comment: From this it is clear that the series converges for any positive sequence $a_n$, so the assumption that $\sum a_n$ diverges is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the numerator and denominator by $a_n$, and compare what you get with $1/n^2$.